# How to change TAX to VAT

Tags: magento2, vat

I'm using Porto theme by Smartwave on Magento 2.2.5 CE. The store is based in the UK. A lot of the terms on Magento 2 are US, so I am just wondering where can I change the particular term TAX to VAT throughout the entire store?

Looking in this directory:

```
app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/i18n
```

I have found `en_US.csv`, however no `en_GB.csv`...even when looking in the static content directory: `/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto/en_GB/i18n`

It shows only `en_US.csv`

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento provides the support to the en_US only if you have created your store in other language then you yourself have to maintain it into the other language

Just simply traverse to the below location

> Admin > Store > Settings > Configuration > General > General

From **Store View**: Select your **store view** & in **Locale Option** select that language in which you want your store view `Locale Option > Locale`

And now traverse to below location

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/i18n

Put your language_CODE.csv file there. For en_GB you can get it from [here](https://github.com/Magento2Translations/language_en_gb)

Set your desired changes there into that file & run the below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f
```

> Note: Make sure you have entered the **language_CODE** when you are
>   deploying the content then only it will create the other language's
>   static content otherwise it will deploys only the en_US content.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and guidance! However upon looking at the .csv file it doesn't contain any replacement for TAX. Would I just add TAX as a value and in the next column add VAT?

Comment: Yes as I already said that set your desired changes into that file you can simply put it like this "original_value","desired_value" make sure that the value (original_value) you are putting there in the csv file is translate able & also should have exact same value means capital letters at place of capital & small letter at the place of small